# On saving the the data with foreign key relations, it throws exception

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

On saving the the data with foreign key relations, it throws Exception

Sensitivity Entity Class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lab_tb_sensitivity")
public class Sensitivity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name=EntityConstants.SQ_NAME, sequenceName=EntityConstants.SQ_SS)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator=EntityConstants.SQ__NAME)
    @Column(name="sensitivity_id")
    private long sensitivityId;

    @Column(name="audit_yn")
    private String auditYn;



    //bi-directional many-to-one association to SensitivityPattern
    @OneToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST,CascadeType.MERGE},fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="sensitivity")
    private Set<SensitivityPattern> SensitivityPattern;

    /** Constructor and getters and setters

}
```

There is a one to many relation ship with SensitivityPattern

SensitivityPattern Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name="lab_tb_sensitivity_pattern")
public class SensitivityPattern implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private SensitivityPatternPK id;

    private String remarks;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="sensitivity_id",  nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Sensitivity sensitivity;

    /**Constructor and geets setters */

}
```

Primary key is a composite key(sensitivityId + abId)
SensitivityPatternPK Entity class
    ---------------------------------

```
@Embeddable
public class SensitivityPatternPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column(name="sensitivity_id")
    private long sensitivityId;

    @Column(name="ab_id")
    private long abId;


    /**Constructor and geets setters */

}
```

On saving code

```
@Override
public boolean saveSensitivityData(List<SensitivityDto> sensitivity) {

    if(sensitivity != null){

        for(SensitivityDto dto : sensitivity) {
            try {
                updateSensitivityPattern(dto);
                super.saveOneEntity(dto);
            } catch (GenericException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

/**
 * To update the sensitivity data.
 * @param dto
 */
private void updateSensitivityPattern(SensitivityDto dto) {
    if(dto != null && dto.getSensitivityPattern() != null){
        for(SensitivityPatternDto sPattern : dto.getSensitivityPattern()  ){
            SensitivityPatternPKDto sensitivityPatternPKDto = new  SensitivityPatternPKDto();
            sensitivityPatternPKDto.setSensitivityId(dto.getSensitivityId());
            sPattern.setId(sensitivityPatternPKDto);
            sPattern.setSensitivity(dto);
        }
}
```

THis is the DAO class to save the data into the database

```
@Transactional(rollbackOn = GenericException.class)
public D saveOneEntity(D dto) throws GenericException {
    T result;
    try {
        result = repository.save(mapper.map(dto, entityClass));
    } catch (DataAccessException dae) {
        throw new GenericException(dae, dae.getRootCause().getMessage());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new GenericException(
                e,
                messageSource.getMessage(CodeEnum.UNKNOWN_EXCEPTION_ON_SAVE_METHOD.getValue(), null, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
    return mapper.map(result, dtoClass);
}
```

On save with the below data on hitting the service with the below data

```
    {
      "sensitivity": [
        {
          "auditYn": "Y",
          "sensitivityPattern": [
            {
              "id": {
                "abId": 11
              },
              "remarks": "test"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

It throws the exception

> "Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update
>   on table "lab_tb_sensitivity_pattern" violates foreign key constraint
>   "fk_sensitivity_id"   Detail: Key (sensitivity_id)=(0) is not present
>   in table "lab_tb_sensitivity".

Answer (score 2):

Please fix following code,

```
 try {
       updateSensitivityPattern(dto);
       super.saveOneEntity(dto);
     } 
 catch (GenericException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

You need to `persist` first the `Sensitivity` and then `SensitivityPattern`.
Currently it fails because there is not such `entity` found hence there is no `id` generated.

Instead do it,

```
try {
       //please verify as per you code
       CorrespondingSentivityDTO persistedDTO = super.saveOneEntity(dto);
       updateSensitivityPattern(persistedDTO);
} 
catch (GenericException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: SensitivityDto persistedDTO = super.saveOneEntity(dto); //this line throwing exception now

Comment: @user630209 what is the exception?

Comment: Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: insert or update on table "lab_tb_sensitivity_pattern" violates foreign key constraint "fk_sensitivity_id"
  Detail: Key (sensitivity_id)=(0) is not present in table "lab_tb_sensitivity".

Comment: super.saveOneEntity(dto); this should not fail on fk_sensitivity_id because it is creating sensitivity entity first. I suspect you have not dont build properly after change

Comment: Commented the updating code, still failed. Is some thing wrong with Entity ?   sensitivity_id I defined in  SensitivityPattern & SensitivityPatternPK classes.

Comment: @user630209 let me explain. Once the entity is persisted (Sensitivity from SensitivityDto) you should get a DTO from saveOneEntity (outClass) with its id. From this then you need to find that Sensitivity entity and set into SensitivityPattern entity so that it gets the entity reference when it is persisted. Please make sure this is happening in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131469/discussion-between-user630209-and-scanqr).

Comment: @ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name="sensitivity_id",  nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private Sensitivity sensitivity; - removed nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false) entries, its working now.

Comment: @user630209 to know. if above suggested change was also required then please it will be great if you accept answer.